# Android: Can i add Tabs within actionBar?

Tags: android, menu, tabs, android-actionbar

I have done practice adding menu on action bar. But for this case I have to add tab in actionbar (**not below the actionbar**) like below figure:

[image]

Please help me to find out the solution. Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can try a simple stuff by creating custom ActionBar like this

You can create custom Action bar like this ..

// gets actionBar reference ..

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

// This sets custom layout to action bar

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_provider);
```

// this is how... .... you get id of layout defined

```
iv_d = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_menu);
```

Now if you need to show stuff like ActionBar tabs then simply provide background on every layout where each layout contains a text and Image... This will provide a look n feel of ActionBar Tab over ActionBar.

Hope it clears your doubt. Let me know if still you have any concern in same.

Thanks.